# Use Specific User's Data in Parse iOS SDK

Tags: parse-platform

When I get support requests from users of my iOS app, it helps immensely to be able to see their data locally in the iOS Simulator.

I want to be able to pull in a specific user's Parse data from within my dev environment (Xcode + Simulator) so I can debug things.

Is there a way to set the current PFUser to be a certain user? I wouldn't ever ship my app with this code, I just want to be able to use it on my dev machine.

Thanks!

Comment: What data would you need to see? I think the main concern here is your asking to be a different user. Even as an admin, that's completely the wrong way of going about things. If I knew the service I was using could easily be me without me knowing I wouldn't like that too much, although I'm sure there are services out there that do this, knowing they do is the problem. Maybe ask your question with different phrasing? Are you trying to get their device info etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, use the `becomeInBackground:` method of the `PFUser` class and pass in the session token of the user you want to 'login as'. The session token should be automatically stored in the `User` object.

To get the sessionToken of a user, make a request to `https://api.parse.com/1/users/{objectId}` and use the master key instead of the REST-API key. This will return the user object and the sessionToken (if there user is logged in)

https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-become/iOS